# I need some help with this.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

How do I find a positively oriented orthonormal basis $ e_1, e_2, e_3$ such that $e_1, e_2$ are parallell to the plane $x + 2y + 4z = 7$ ?
Can I use the normal of the plane and say that is $e_3$ and then that $ e_1 and  \thinspace e_2$ is parallell to it?? How do I tackle this problem? 
The problem is in linear algebra.

Comment: @NormalHuman, hey if you're ever running for a moderator, you have my voice :D Sorry for the offoptic, OP.

Comment: Pick two vectors parallel to your plane and one outside of it, then apply [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). You can save yourself a bit of computation by choosing two vectors normal to each other.

Comment: You'll get more attention for your question if you give it a descriptive title. "I need some help with this" doesn't really impart any information, on a site where every question is presumably posted by someone needing help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The vector normal to the plane is $\vec u=(1,2,4)^T$.

Chose two vectors on the plane, e.g. $\vec a=(1,1,1)^T$ and $\vec b=(1,0,3/2)^T$ (note that the components verify the equation of the plane) and take $\vec v=\vec a-\vec b$ that is parallel to the plane, so orthogonal to $\vec u$.

Take another vector $\vec w=\vec u \times \vec v$. ( that, by construction, is orthogonal to $\vec u$ and $\vec v$)

Normalize the three vectors and you have an orthonormal basis:
$$
\vec e_1=\dfrac{\vec w}{|\vec w|} \qquad \vec e_2=\dfrac{\vec v}{|\vec v|} \qquad \vec e_3=\dfrac{\vec u}{|\vec u|} 
$$
with $\vec e_1$ and $\vec e_2$ parallel to the plane